# One case statement across multiple columns

Tags: mysql

I have a query in which I am executing the same case statement across multiple columns, i.e. something like this

```
select
case when (cond) then
     'Column1 Cond T'
else'Column1 Cond F'
end,
case when (cond) then
     'Column2 Cond T'
else'Column2 Cond F'
end,
from table
```

I would like to "merge" these two case statement into one so I have something like this:

```
 SELECT
 CASE WHEN (cond) then
     'Column1 Cond T', 'Column2 Cond T'
ELSE 'Column1 Cond F','Column2 Cond F'
END,
FROM table
```

However, I am getting a syntax error when I try running that. What is the correct syntax for this type of case statement?

Comment: What you want is not possible, the `case` expression returns only a single scalar value.

Answer (score 4):

Store the condition result into user variable and use it in the second `CASE`:

```
select
case when @cond := (cond) then
     'Column1 Cond T'
else'Column1 Cond F'
end,
case when @cond then
     'Column2 Cond T'
else'Column2 Cond F'
end,
from table
```

Comment: Thanks Akina. However, I would ideally want to write down that case statement only once - is that possible?

Comment: One `CASE` can assign any value to one field only. I don't see the way to realize the trick you want in common case... maybe it's some particular solution (for example, move `cond` calculation to pseudotable in `FROM` section).

Answer (score 1):

Your query is very simplified, I presume for security reasons.  But this pattern below (written for MSSQL) should work for you.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Test
    (
    TestID INT NOT NULL
    , Column1 VARCHAR(100) NULL
    , Column2 VARCHAR(100) NULL
    )

SELECT T.TestID
    , COALESCE(U.Column1, T.Column1)
    , COALESCE(U.Column2, T.Column2)
FROM dbo.Test AS T
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (   SELECT TestID, Column1, Column2
                        FROM dbo.Test
                        WHERE Column1 = 'ConditionMet'
                        ) AS U ON U.TestID = T.TestID
```